# Pushable div for both sides

Tags: html, push

How am I able to make a div push content (off screen) to both sides (right and left)?

Currently i'm using property overflow: hidden (so whenever I scale up an image the content on the right side will be hidden, but i'd also like to have the same effect for the left side).

Example (see red arrow):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't. At least not in a straightforward way.

This is how the basic mechanism of a document work. The content stacks inline from left to right, and in rows from up to down.

To create the effect you're describing you'd have to make use of JavaScript. For example, the parent container of all the images, may have its position: relative and, any time an image is selected, is moved half of the image size to the left, setting its left css property.

Comment: I want to achieve this in JQuery to be honest, could you throw me an example of doing this? I tried giving the main container a negative margin-left. But the effect is horrible, since the whole div is moving to the left and the 'hover' wouldn't match the cursor position anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap elements with positioning:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="moving-wrapper">
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
     width: 100%; 
     position: relative;
}
.moving-wrapper {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
}
.element {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 100px;
}
```

jQuery

```
 //example clicking a element
 $('.element').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var position = $(this).offset;
       $('.moving-wrapper').animate({ left: (position.left * -1) },250);
 });
```

Please, note that is a fast example, but it is the idea.

Comment: Already have those settings sir, the only problem i'm facing is that the content is being pushed to the right side (since that's the only possible way according to the language we use). I wanted to solve this problem using negative margins when hovering (in JQuery) but ain't getting a good effect tbh

Comment: I think that I understand you now. What negative margins you tested?

Comment: I think that this can help you: https://jsfiddle.net/7t4adoc5/ Is it the problem? If not, I don't understand you. Sorry.

Comment: I tried giving it a -70px whenever i'm hovering the last item, it works but what if 70px is too much (in this case a smaller screen responsive design).  I want the system to push it automatically so there won't be any calculations needed (in case there will be mistakes, etc)

Comment: Please, if you make a fiddle with the exact problem you have we can help you better.